# Pie Chart - Move Data Labels off Chart

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

As you can see from following picture, I need to automatically adjust data label to be off the chart. Value for pie changes through week, and for some reason access always place them on the chart.  How to remove it or place it somewhere where they will not effect chart (If I can place them next to each other - it should be fine.)

I'm using MS Access 2013 for this project, and user is using MS Access RunTime 2013.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting, found where MS Access has option for where to place data labels.

After selecting both data labels, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (Selected Data Labels... form), under Alignment there is option where you have to specify where you like to have data labels.  Outside end option is what I was after.

[image]